# Wordpress installation falsely successful but doesn't show anything

Tags: wordpress

When I install wordpress on my server, all I get on my homepage is hello world. Just those two words. Nothing else. No headers, no footers, no errors anywhere. Same thing with when I login as admin - just two words, no dashboard whatsoever.

I have tried using cPanel installer, and just dumping files on the server, but all is fruitless.

Suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have an `.htaccess` file? If not, create one in your root directory and add this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

[WordPress .htaccess](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

Comment: @varvara-jones Can you access the admin? Do you have a theme activated?

Comment: no I could not. But apparently having an .htaccess was imperative to my server. I always, always forget.